# Changing Timezone for GCal Events

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a "List" view of events coming directly from Google Calendar.  The Google Calendar is set to the 'America/Central' Time zone.   I need to display the events in 'America/Eastern' Time Zone.

I have found examples, but can't seem to get them to work. I am providing my base code in hopes that someone can help me out.

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/gcal.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js'></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'list',
    defaultDate: '2019-01-20',
    duration:  {
        days: 180
    },

      header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },

      displayEventTime: true, // don't show the time column in list view
        height: 450,

      // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
      // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
      // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'REALKEY',

      // US Holidays
      events: 'REALCALENDAR',

      eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
      },

      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }

    });

  });



</script>
<style>


  #loading {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
```

Currently my events are being displayed in just UTC.

Comment: Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone yet?

Comment: I have and I have been trying what is in it and I can't seem to get the events to change time.  I am not getting any errors when I do it, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Also fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone seems like something you do at the events level and my stuff is being populated straight fro GCal so I am not looking at that level of things in my code.

Comment: as it says in that documentation, you first need to check whether the data coming back from google contains timezone info. Check the network tools in your browser to see what's being downloaded. Yes, it's event-level stuff...so you need to check your event data. The fact it's being populated automatically by a script doesn't change the fact that it needs to be compliant.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what that code looks like?  I appreciate it?

Comment: what code? I suggested to look at the _data_ using your browser's debugging tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out.

I had to add both timezone and timezoneParam to get the calendar to adjust the time to the right timezone.  Here is my final code with the keys removed.

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/gcal.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js'></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'list',
    defaultDate: '2019-04-01',


    timezone: 'America/New_York',
    timezoneParam   : "America/New_York",


    duration:  {
        days: 7
    },

      header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
      },

      displayEventTime: true, // don't show the time column in list view
        height: 450,

      // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
      // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
      // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'YOUR_KEY',

      // US Holidays
      events: 'YOUR_CALENDAR@group.calendar.google.com',

      eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
      },

      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }

    });

  });


</script>
```